# React Native: How to navigate to a page?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, frontend, mobile-application

> The below code is of Menu.js .I want to navigate to Settings.js by clicking on Settings .
> I mentioned the code of Menu.js below.
> Can I use the onPress to navigate to the next page wheni click on something?

> I don't understand how to add this feature in the below code to the items.

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, TextInput, View, StyleSheet ,TouchableOpacity,Image,Button,
                ImageBackground,FlatList,StatusBar,SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';



const DATA = [
  {
    id: "bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba",
    title: "Tasks Done",
  },
  {
    id: "3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63",
    title: "Goals",
  },
  {
    id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72",
    title: "Rank",
  },

   {
         id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d74",
         title: "Week Plan",
       },
   {
         id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d73",
         title: "Settings",
       },
];

const Item = ({ item, onPress, style }) => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={[styles.item, style]}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);

const Menu = () => {
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    const backgroundColor = item.id === selectedId ? "#6e3b6e" : "#f9c2ff";

    return (
      <Item
        item={item}
        onPress={() => setSelectedId(item.id)}
        style={{ backgroundColor }}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        extraData={selectedId}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0,
  },
  item: {
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 25,
  },
});

export default Menu;
```

> I want to navigate to Settings.js as soon as I click on settings .
> But I don't want to lose existing function of color changing .

> How do I do this??

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is worth looking at the official docs here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/navigation

Official docs recommend react navigation, have a look at react navigation: https://reactnavigation.org/

Integrate this navigation in your project, once you have this you'd be able to user the navigation.navigate(nameOfYourView).